# Text selection events in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Which event can i use to get the currnt selected text in a React component? The text is wrappend with a div and is not paart of a HTML form.

for example, get the texxt selected in blue.[image]

Comment: @Chris This is in the right direction but how can i attach that event only to specific react components since this is a global event

Comment: Just create a function as shown in the linked answer and trigger it on the component you want with `onMouseUp`.

Comment: @Chris Nice idea. thank you i will try it